# How to pass string from app to another in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, parameter-passing

- How can I send a String from one **Flutter** app to another?

I find this package called **uni_links**, it may help me,

- But how to send data?

I'm using **deviceapps** package to open my second app.

- Is there a way to set parameters to the app I'm opening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using this library, [share_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/share) you can share the text with other apps.
In order to receiver share intents, the other app must be built with [receive_share_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent).

For example:
You can use `Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');` to share text with text sharing apps like WhatsApp.